# How to convert datetime UTC to local time Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have UTC time in database.

I want to convert this time to local time in format dd.mm.yy h.m.s

How to do that?

My date is in UTC:

```
2019-08-08 08:57:59
```

In need local time +4:00

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just append UTC before converting:

```
let yourDate = new Date('08/08/2019 12:22:48 PM UTC');
yourDate.toString();
```

OR:

```
let yourDate = new Date('08/08/2019 12:22:48 UTC');
yourDate.toString();
```

In addition you can use `pipe` which uses locale to display date in user's timezone. Try with client's timezone data::

```
<p>The date is {{today | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</p>
```

**Update:**

For your case:

```
let dateString = '2019-08-08 08:57:59';
let yourDate: Date = new Date(dateString + ' UTC');
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{ today | date : 'EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm:ss' }} {{ today | date : 'a' | lowercase }}
```

if your time looks like '2019-08-08T08:57:59' then just concat 'z' at the end to state it as UTC then run through date pipe like

```
<div>{{ today+'Z' | date : 'EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm:ss' }}</div>
```

Comment: This is date from database: `08/08/2019 12:22:48 PM UTC`?

Comment: @OPV you can write any format you want. The main requirement is just add `UTC`.

Comment: It does not work for me, it gives UTC format: <p>The date is {{today | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</p>

Comment: My date is in UTC: `2019-08-08 08:57:59`

Comment: this will not work in Safari. It returns NaN/Invalid Date.

Answer (score 8):

Using angulars date pipe. Either:

HTML

`{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}`

or 
Typescript

`formatDate(value_expression, format, timezone, locale )`

Answer (score 1):

Append 'UTC' to the string before converting it

```
var date = new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');
date.toString() // "Wed Jun 29 2011 09:52:48 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

Comment: It does not work for date: `2019-08-08 08:57:59`

Comment: @OPV you can reformat your date